# PHP::Reference or copy (case inside)?

Tags: php, reference

Please help me to prove about the case if variable reference or copy.

Case1 - $arr copy or reference?:

```
class Ex1{
 public static $var1=array(10=>'work', 20=>'home'); 
}
$arr=Ex1::$var1;
```

Case2 - $arr copy or reference?:

```
 class Ex1{
     protected static $var1=array(10=>'work', 20=>'home'); 
     public static function getArr(){
      return self::$var1;
       }
    }
    $arr=Ex1::getArr();
```

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: What? Could please explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By my reckoning, it should be a copy.

```
class Ex1{
    public static $var1=array(10=>'work', 20=>'home');
}

$arr=Ex1::$var1;

var_dump($arr);

$arr[15] = 'play';

var_dump($arr);

$arr2=Ex1::$var1;

var_dump($arr2);

Ex1::$var1 = array(10=>'work', 15=>'asylum', 20=>'home');

$arr3=Ex1::$var1;

var_dump($arr3);

var_dump($arr2);
```

gives

```
array
  10 => string 'work' (length=4)
  20 => string 'home' (length=4)

array
  10 => string 'work' (length=4)
  20 => string 'home' (length=4)
  15 => string 'play' (length=4)

array
  10 => string 'work' (length=4)
  20 => string 'home' (length=4)

array
  10 => string 'work' (length=4)
  15 => string 'asylum' (length=6)
  20 => string 'home' (length=4)

array
  10 => string 'work' (length=4)
  20 => string 'home' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Both copy. Only objects are transmitted by reference by default.

Comment: @Yosef - if you need proof, try running my sample code and believe what your eyes show you (changes to the copies don't affect the value of the original, or vice versa)... if you need a mathematical level of proof, then you're better off reading through the actual source code of PHP, or asking the actual developers of PHP (and see what their response is to your request). But __why__ do you need this proof?

Comment: Object also transmitted as copy

Comment: @Yosef - Objects are different. Objects aren't copies, but are references (which is exactly what tobyS has said). Your example used an array, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `$arr` and then `var_dump(Ex1::getArr());` and you'll see if it was a copy or a reference.

edit: didn't see Ex1::var1 was protected

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a copy, test it like:

```
$arr=Ex1::$var1;
$arr['omg'] = 'lol';
var_dump($arr);
var_dump(Ex1::$var1);
```